# Getting start with solr with mean.io?

Tags: solr, faceted-search, mean.io

Hi I am new in solr and i am looking for any guide line so that i can learn and use solr in my web application ?
I am using mean.io stack http://www.mean.io for development.
Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Well, *mean* is a stack. So you should be looking for whatever the individual components are. So you probably want a [Node client library for Solr](http://lbdremy.github.io/solr-node-client/).

Solr supports JSON for a lot of operations and for the output format (wt=json), so it should not be too difficult to work with from the Javascript stack

Comment: Hi Thanx for reply. I just want to know that is there way to use solr example/solr in my web application ?

Comment: You run Solr as a standalone server. Then you talk to it from your application. Try the tutorials, both the one online and the one in the docs directory of Solr. They will make things a lot clearer.